# Matplotlib uneven grid imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have plot the contents of 5 numpy arrays as images with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`. Code example below:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3)
fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)
axarr[0, 0].imshow(img1)
axarr[0, 0].axis('off')
axarr[0, 1].imshow(img2)
axarr[0, 1].axis('off')
axarr[0, 2].imshow(img3)
axarr[0, 2].axis('off')
axarr[1, 0].imshow(img4)
axarr[1, 0].axis('off')
axarr[1, 2].imshow(img5)
axarr[1, 2].axis('off')
axarr[1, 1].axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.savefig(predictions)
plt.close()
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Example plot]

How can I plot the images so that the 2 images on the bottom row are side-by-side and centered on that row please?

Comment: How does side-by-side and centered look like? I can currently imagine at least 3 different ways.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I realise I was a bit vague! swatchai's output is what I was looking for. However, as commented, the approach would not allow certain features such as figure titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. Here is a working code to produce one of them. In the code, images are appended side-by-side to get only 2 resulting images that are plotted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make up images for demo purposes
raw = np.random.randint(10, size=(6,6))
im0 = (raw >= 5) * 1                     # get either 0 or 1 in the array
im1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(6,6))  # get 0-9 in the array

# combine them to get 2 different images
im_01 = np.append(im0, im1, axis=1)      # 2 images (O+1), side-by-side combined
im_010 = np.append(im_01, im0, axis=1)   # 3 images (O+1+0)

# create figure with 2 axes in 2 rows, 1 column
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
width = 10
fig.set_size_inches((width, width/2.))  # need proper (width, height) ratio

# plot (3 combined) image in row1
ax0.imshow( im_010 )
ax0.axis('off')

# plot (2 combined) image in row2
ax1.imshow( im_01 )
ax1.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is the difficulties in plotting other info accompanying each original images.

Comment: Yes, that's a creative solution, but I was hoping to add figure titles for each image! I wonder if matplotlib is the right tool for my purpose?